# Can specify image size in Yahoo Image Search API?

Tags: image, api, yahoo, yahoo-api

is it possible to specify the sizes of images with yahoo images api?

Here is the [docs](http://developer.yahoo.com/search/image/V1/imageSearch.html). Nothing about this future. And it's available in web interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the original Yahoo Image Search API did not allow specifying the image size. (That service was also deprecated as of April 2011, so it's not much use now.)

The [Bing Search APIs](http://www.bing.com/toolbox/bingdeveloper/) do allow for a sized image search. Look for the "filter" options in the request, with sourcetype set to images.